# How can i put text in disabled <input> with selenium chrome driver and c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-chromedriver

Hellow, i have  element on web page, that is disabled. Here it is: [disabled element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2k6W.jpg)

```
<input id="uploadPdfFileName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Test" title="Test" disabled="disabled">
```

i tried put some text in it with selenium sendKeys() method, but i got this:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException : invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

How can i put text in this element with selenium chrome driver and c#? Maybe i must try some other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe to set the text before and then disable it with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I change "disabled" attribute to false with ExecuteScript() selenium method, before putting text in input with sendKeys(). It woks.